# Creation of a soft-matter tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I realized there is no tag about soft-matter, the branch of condensed matter / statistical physics. Would be great to add it, isn't it ?

Comment: It'd be nice to also include a bit in the wiki for the tag. But I know from experience that can be a good deal of work to make it look real good. At the very least, though, there should probably be a tag excerpt, and it should say enough so that people who see the popup text won't confuse this tag for `soft-question`. This also helps ignorant people like me understand that soft matter is not some new name for dark matter or something. :)

Comment: @ChrisWhite I've tried something, but it's hard. It's really a vast field difficult to summarise

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, but you don't have to ask on meta to create a tag. Just put it on a few questions. (Ones where it belongs, of course.)

Comment: Ok, sorry then for the spam of the meta. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you find a fair number of questions that belong to the topic, sure, go ahead! To create the tag just add it to the questions. (if there are many such questions don't do it all at once to avoid flooding the main page)